# React-Native configuration issue

Tags: react-native, webpack, expo, metro-bundler

I have a cloned git project.

It uses "Webpack", expo, metroBundler

After I run script to web version of expo:

Starting Metro Bundler Starting Webpack on port 19006 in development mode.

Then I get 138 errors in console, the app is on localhost but nothing is rendered on the screen.

One of them as an example:

ERROR in "./node_modules/victory-native/*(as anything after, there are couple of them)"
Module not found: Can't resolve @shopify/react-native-skia

Because of this line

```
const react_native_skia_1 = require("@shopify/react-native-skia");
```

What could be the problem? Webpack? Babel? Appreaciate the assistance

I tried everything, installed new dependencies, tried to configure Babel or Webpack, nothing.